# Change TextView background color in ListView with simple adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter, listadapter

I have a ListView which displays a list with two TextViews. On one of them, I want to apply a specific color. All the data (and colors) are provided by a Json file from web service.

I use a simple adapter which I want to use. Could someone indicate how to put the specific color for each item?

Here is my class:

```
public class NetworkTimeTableFragment extends Fragment {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private static String mylat;
    private static String mylng;

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "shop_name";
    private static final String TAG_SHORT = "shop_address";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "shop_url";
    private static final String TAG_COLOR = "feuilletez";
    TextView shop_address;
    TextView shop_name;
    TextView shop_url;
    ImageButton feuilletez;
    private ListView list;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public NetworkTimeTableFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timetable, container, false);

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetJson().execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetJson extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            String myurl = "routes.json";

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(myurl, ServiceHandler.GET);

            JSONArray array = null;
            try {
                array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                    System.out.println("id --->" + id);
                    String url = jsonObject.getString("url");
                    System.out.println("url --->" + url);
                    String created_at = jsonObject.getString("created_at");
                    System.out.println("created_at --->" + created_at);
                    String updated_at = jsonObject.getString("updated_at");
                    System.out.println("updated_at --->" + updated_at);
                    String short_name = jsonObject.getString("short_name");
                    System.out.println("short_name --->" + short_name);
                    String long_name = jsonObject.getString("long_name");
                    System.out.println("long_name --->" + long_name);
                    String desc = jsonObject.getString("desc");
                    System.out.println("desc --->" + desc);
                    String type = jsonObject.getString("type");
                    System.out.println("type --->" + type);
                    String type_name = jsonObject.getString("type_name");
                    System.out.println("type_name --->" + type_name);
                    String color = jsonObject.getString("color");
                    System.out.println("color --->" + color);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, long_name);
                    map.put(TAG_SHORT, short_name);
                    map.put(TAG_COLOR, color);
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    oslist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(),
                    oslist,
                    R.layout.listview_routes_row,
                    new String[]{TAG_NAME, TAG_SHORT, TAG_COLOR},
                    new int[]{R.id.long_name, R.id.short_name});

            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    //  Intent intent = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, NewsActivity.class);
                    //intent.putExtra("shopurl",oslist.get(+position).get(TAG_URL));
                    // overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animationin, R.anim.animationout);
                    //  startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only one one item? which one?

Comment: the list display a list of items. Each item has a specific color and two text view. I want this color to appear on one of the Textview.

Comment: See my answer, it is what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way to achieve what you want is to create custom adapter. **Here** I am giving you an example to achieve your goal...

**Activity Layout**---> **activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**List Item Layout**---> **listview_routes_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/long_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/short_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Custom SimpleAdapte**---> **CustomSimpleAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    private List<Map<String, Object>> itemList;
    private Context mContext;
    private static final String TAG_COLOR = "color";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "shop_name";
    private static final String TAG_SHORT = "shop_address";

    public CustomSimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,  
            int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);

        this.itemList = (List<Map<String, Object>>) data;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    /* A Static class for holding the elements of each List View Item
     * This is created as per Google UI Guideline for faster performance */
    class ViewHolder {
        TextView textLong;
        TextView textShort;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_routes_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            // get the textview's from the convertView
            holder.textLong = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.long_name);
            holder.textShort = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.short_name);

            // store it in a Tag as its the first time this view is generated
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            /* get the View from the existing Tag */
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        /* update the textView's text and color of list item */
        holder.textLong.setText((CharSequence) itemList.get(position).get(TAG_NAME));
        holder.textShort.setText((CharSequence) itemList.get(position).get(TAG_SHORT));
        holder.textShort.setTextColor((Integer) itemList.get(position).get(TAG_COLOR));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**Activity Class**---> **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG_NAME = "shop_name";
    private static final String TAG_SHORT = "shop_address";
    private static final String TAG_COLOR = "color";

    private List<Map<String, Object>> itemList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    private Map<String, Object> map;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        //Sample data insertion into the list
        map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put(TAG_NAME, "textview11");
        map.put(TAG_SHORT, "textview12");
        map.put(TAG_COLOR, Color.BLUE);
        itemList.add(map);

        map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put(TAG_NAME, "textview21");
        map.put(TAG_SHORT, "textview22");
        map.put(TAG_COLOR, Color.GREEN);
        itemList.add(map);

        map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put(TAG_NAME, "textview31");
        map.put(TAG_SHORT, "textview32");
        map.put(TAG_COLOR, Color.RED);
        itemList.add(map);

        /* create an adapter for listview*/
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new CustomSimpleAdapter(this, itemList,
                R.layout.listview_routes_row, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_SHORT }, new 
                int[] { R.id.long_name, R.id.short_name });

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

I think it will help you. If you have any problem then let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much Hamid, I'll give it a try this morning and I'll let you know.

Comment: The custom adapter is working fine to retrieve TAG_NAME and TAG_SHORT but I've got a NPE on TAG_COLOR on this line of the adapter :  holder.textShort.setTextColor((Integer) itemList.get(position).get(TAG_COLOR));

Comment: 02-04 10:52:40.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10689): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 10:52:40.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10689): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 10:52:40.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10689):  at com.begital.vitalis.adapter.CustomSimpleAdapter.getView(CustomSimpleAdapter.java:63)
02-04 10:52:40.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10689):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2271)
02-04 10:52:40.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10689):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)

Comment: probably you forgot to insert color value in the map from where you want retrieve the color...I have run my code again but I did not get any error...please, have a look in your code.

Comment: my color format is like= color: "0000FF", maybe it's the reason?

Comment: yeah..."0000FF" is hexa value but in example TAG_COLOR is assigned with int value of color.

Comment: how do change this line :  holder.textShort.setTextColor((Integer) itemList.get(position).get(TAG_COLOR)); to get the hexavalue?

Comment: **1.** In **MainActivity**, **Color.RED** in **map.put(TAG_COLOR, Color.RED);** will be replaced by by **"#0000FF"**...be carefull, hexa value should be followed by # in double quote as string.

**2.** in Apdapter class **holder.textShort.setTextColor((Integer) itemList.get(position).get(TAG_COLOR));** will be replaced by **holder.textShort.setTextColor(Color.parseColor( (String) itemList.get(position).get(TAG_COLOR)));**

Comment: Not yet, still got the issue with color. I did String color = jsonObject.getString("color"); 
     String colored = ("#"+ color); and list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
             
                SimpleAdapter adapter = new CustomSimpleAdapter(getActivity(), itemList,
                        R.layout.listview_routes_row, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_SHORT, TAG_COLOR }, new 
                        int[] { R.id.long_name, R.id.short_name });

                list.setAdapter(adapter); but it is not working

Comment: I think the issue is, i'm using that list view inside a fragment, and your code is for an activity. I just realized that now. Do you know how to adapt it for a fragment?

Answer (score 2):

For creating custom view for each item you'll have to create your own adapter instead of using the defaults one, but it's pretty easy:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        Object item = getItem(position);
        TextView text = v.findViewById(//your text view id);
        ColorStateList color = //get color for item;
        text.setTextColor(color);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not familiar with android dev. So I must create a new class for the custom adapter and then call it in my class, but how I use it?

Comment: Just create this class, you can do it in your current class as inner class or in a separate file as another class. then just call `CustomAdapter` ctor instead `SimpleAdapter` that you used.

Comment: Thank you, I'm giving it a try.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:textview.setTextColor(color);